# Update a field for a specific # of records in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Say I want 3 records flagged for each product in my table. But if some products only get 1 or 2 records flagged or even no records flagged, how can I make it randomly flag the remaining records up to the total of 3 per product.

Ex:

1 record gets flagged for Product_A, 2 records get flagged for Product_B and 3 records get flagged for Product_C.

Once script is complete, I need 2 more records flagged for Product_A and 1 more for Product_B.

This can be a loop or a cte or whatever is the most efficient way to do this in sql. Thanks!

Comment: Does it matter which three records get flagged for a product, or do you have a reason for selecting one or two records manually then picking the last record(s) at random?

Comment: First I run a cte to flag records based on a flag in the table. Some products may get all 3 records flagged and some less than 3. If this is run first and not all 3 records get flagged, how do I know how many more to flag to get to 3. Below would work if all 3 records are flagged but what if less than 3 are flagged.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```
;with SelectedIds as(
  select 
    Id,
    row_number() over (
      partition by ProductCode -- distinct numbering for each Product Code
      order by newid() -- random
    ) as rowno
  from ProductLines
)
update p
  set IsFlagged = 1
from ProductLines p
join SelectedIds s
  on p.id = s.id and
      s.rowno <= 3 -- limit to 3 records / product code
;
```

Here's a full sample, including some test data: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3bee1/6

Comment: This works for what I asked for but lets make it more interesting. Say I want to flag 1 record per product code with a shirt_color = red and 1 record where shirt_color is blue and 1 record where shirt_color is green. And if 3 records are NOT flagged for each product code, then randomly flag the remaining records for each product code until the total flagged = 3 is reached.

Comment: @user2635406 that would easily be solved by adding `, shirt_color` to the `partition by` clause and doing `s.rowno <= 1` in the last row

Answer (score 0):

Use `row_number()` in a derived table where the numbers are generated so the rows that already have flags come first and the rest are ordered randomly and partition by `Product`. If random is not a requirement you can just remove `newid()` from the query.

Set the flag for the rows number 1-3 if the row is not already flagged.

```
update T
set Flag = 1
from (
     select Flag,
            row_number() over(partition by Product
                              order by Flag desc, newid()) as rn
     from YourTable
     ) as T
where T.rn <= 3 and
      T.Flag = 0
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/220df/2)